# Load ES6/ESM modules in browser from non-http sources?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I'd like to load ESM modules in the web browser from a non-HTTP source, in my case a ZIP file bundle of many modules, stored on IPFS.

Basically I want to implement the equivalent of a Python import hook, or a Java classloader, in browser Javascript. Is there any means to achieve this?

Here's options I've explored:

1. Using an IPFS<->HTTP gateway: this could work if I was trying to load modules from a directory stored in IPFS, but I want to load from a zip file (ala a Java jar). Additionally, it requires a gateway, which sort of gets in the way of the fun of distributed apps ;-)
2. Load from IPFS, store in a Data URI, load ESM module from a data URI: this works for *single file* ESM modules, but it doesn't work if the ESM module loads another module using a relative path. Maybe there's some way to store folders in a Data URI with sub-paths? I haven't found it tho....

Comment: You could go the Service Worker route, and have it load your files from the ZIP file.  The downside here though is that browser developers have essentially crippled this functionality in various privacy modes and on certain types of reloading.  (Frankly, it's a bit unimaginative that they didn't give us the capability to use a Service Worker for things outside of caching, because it's truly perfect for these types of scenarios.)  Outside of that... is there any reason you can't use a bundler?  Does it have to be in a ZIP file as separate modules?

Comment: Maybe... is it possible for you to do some sort of static analysis and sort of rewrite the JS client-side?  Might even be more feasible to just use one of the existing bundlers client-side.  A lot to load, but might be worth it for your use.

Comment: [`System.loader`](https://github.com/whatwg/loader) was meant to solve this but is abandoned.

Comment: @Brad I actually had tried the static analysis route using webpack, but its honestly probably too slow for my usage, and tricky to get right to boot. Service workers are intruiging! I hadn't even considered that angle, and it does seem like a good fit for the "create something like a data uri but with relative URI fragment references left intact".